# Passing multiple parameters to a function

Tags: jquery

How can I pass two parameters in a function?

what i've tried:

```
function loadweek(loader,button){
  var button_2 = button + "_2";
  alert(button_2);
  alert(button);
  alert(loader);
}

$("#load_week").click(function () {
        loadweek("#load_weekme","#load_week");
});
```

`alert(loader);` is working, but the button is "undefined"

Comment: are you trying to get the objects themselves here?

Comment: You are passing two parameters

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/XJesG/.

Comment: you better provide your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `button` is undefined because there does not exist an element in your document with the `id` of `load_week_2`. Double check your code.

The way you're passing the parameters is actually correct, as seen by the success of the `loader` parameter.

**Update:**

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SY5Jz/1/

Comment: load_week_2 is there 100%

Comment: I'll make you a fiddle then to prove that what you're doing is right :)